# How to tell TypeScript that I know a method exists?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Consider this code:

```
export default class OptimizelyFeatureFlags implements FeatureFlags {
    private body: string;

    constructor(
        protected callEndpoint: CacheableEntity,
        protected baseUrl: string,
        protected envName: string,
        protected featureId: string
    ) {}

    /**
     * Calls the Optimizely endpoint to get the info
     */
    public async fetch(): Promise<void> {

        // Determine if this is a CallEndpoint (or child thereof)
        if (this.callEndpoint['hasAuthorisationToken'] != undefined) {
            if (!this.callEndpoint.hasAuthorisationToken()) {
                throw Error(
                    'This endpoint requires an auth token to work'
                );
            }
        }

        this.body = await this.callEndpoint.getResource(this.baseUrl + `/v2/features/${this.featureId}`);
    }

   ...

}
```

Now `CacheableEntity` is an interface, which requires only `getResource()` to match the contract. The method `hasAuthorisationToken` is not defined within it.

Now, if a class has a `hasAuthorisationToken()` method, I know it is a `CallEndpoint`, which will  implement `CacheableEntity`. This is a type test - from my research I understand that TypeScript does not offer run-time type tests, since at run-time it is merely JavaScript.

However, this won't compile. In a Jest test, I get:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/service/feature-flags/OptimizelyFeatureFlags.ts:31:36 - error TS2339: Property 'hasAuthorisationToken' does not exist on type 'CacheableEntity'.

    31             if (!this.callEndpoint.hasAuthorisationToken()) {
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I guess there are several ways around this - maybe I can cast the object from CacheableEntity to CallEndpoint? I want to tell the transpiler that I know what I am doing.

Alternatively I could do something like this:

```
if (this.callEndpoint['hasAuthorisationToken'] != undefined) {
    const hasAuth = this.callEndpoint['hasAuthorisationToken']();
    ...
}
```

However, I wonder if that is a bit messy. What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah your first option is the best one. Most readable.

```
if (this.callEndpoint['hasAuthorisationToken'] != undefined) {
    const callEndpoint = this.callEndpoint as CallEndpoint;
    const hasAuth = callEndpoint.hasAuthorisationToken();
    ...
}
```

Not sure on the `!= undefined` bit. can you do `this.callEndpoint instanceof CallEndpoint` instead? not sure how you're instantiating these things, but if you can use `instanceof`, typescript will accept the call to the method on `this.callEndpoint` without the cast. Like so:

```
if (this.callEndpoint instanceof CallEndpoint) {
    const hasAuth = this.callEndpoint.hasAuthorisationToken();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, that second option is brilliant - thanks. Not only did it work, but my WebStorm-based editor understands inside the conditional that `hasAuthorisationToken()` is now available as a method. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a user defined type guard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: Great stuff, thanks - I am new to my TS journey. I think I have some more reading to do { halo }.